# How can I concatenate thousands of files into a single device

Tags: devices, cat, split, device-mapper

I'am using `split` to cut a an iso into multiples chunks. Then a can use `cat` to rebuild initial iso that I can convert into a mountable device with `losetup` and then mount.

The problem is when initial iso is too big, I cannot create a new fresh iso from chunks because I cannot duplicate the size of this iso.

So my question is : How can I tell losetup (or other program) to create the same device from thousands of chunks?

I've already seen inapplicable solutions making one loop device for each chunk and then using `mdadm` to concatenate these devices, but this solution is not good for me because of the big number of chunks.

Have someone an idea?

**EDIT** : I would like to mount these chunks in read/write mode.

Comment: Try a nbd device using `nbd-server -m`. If that works for you, please feel free to answer your own question with details on how to do it. I won't have time to do it myself.

Comment: Not being able to properly test it, I'm not attempting to answer in a real answer, but a potential thing could be to read the ISO file from a process substitution like `<( cat isopart* )`.

Comment: Are the chunk sizes multiples of 512 bytes? If so, [`dmsetup` with proper map](https://superuser.com/a/1167639/432690) should work, although I have never used it with thousands of files. Another approach is to take the first chunk, append the second, remove the second; append the third, remove the third; and so on. This way you can rebuild the big file. At any given time you need extra space only for one chunk. Do it if you don't mind losing the chunks.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve by cutting the iso into chunks?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will give a try to all of them and if there is one working, I will give an anwser.

For @jsotola, the probleme I'm trying to solve is to synchronize big iso avec network, when ISO is writable. This is typically the case when my iso is an encrypted file system that I want to synchronise over the Internet. When I modify the content of the ISO, I don't want the entire ISO to be resynchronized, but only parts that have been modified.

Comment: iso9660 is read-only, you won't be able to write to it. Or by iso, do you mean an image of any sort of filesystem?

Comment: Why *thosusands* of files?! We aren't using 8" floppies anymore to ship data around...